# Unity connect a Character Class to a UI Toggle

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a Character Selection. When I tick a toggle, it should say "You selected class xy". I already got the active Toggle of the Toggle Group, I just do not know how to connect it to another object.

I divided my Scripts into 3 parts, Data, View and Controller.

My view:
public class ClassSelectionCommonView : MonoBehaviour

```
{
    [SerializeField]
    ToggleGroup toggleGroup; // Get the Toggle Group of the Scene

    public Toggle GetActiveToggle() // Return the single active Toggle
    {
        return toggleGroup.ActiveToggles().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

My Data:

```
public class ClassSelectionCommonData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; } // The characters stats
    public float MovementSpeed { get; set; }
    public float LifePoints { get; set; }
    public float DamageReduction { get; set; }
    public float AttackDamageMelee { get; set; }
    public float AttackDamageRange { get; set; }
    public float AttackSpeed { get; set; }
    public float GoldFind { get; set; }

    private ClassSelectionCommonData templar = new ClassAlchemist(); // Create Character Classes
    private ClassSelectionCommonData inquisitor = new ClassInquisitor();
    private ClassSelectionCommonData hunter = new ClassHunter();
    private ClassSelectionCommonData warlord = new ClassWarlord();
    private ClassSelectionCommonData bandit = new ClassBandit();
    private ClassSelectionCommonData alchemist = new ClassAlchemist();
    private ClassSelectionCommonData engineer = new ClassEngineer();
    private ClassSelectionCommonData thief = new ClassThief();
    private ClassSelectionCommonData occultist = new ClassOccultist();
}
```

And the Controller:

```
public class ClassSelectionCommonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    ClassSelectionCommonData data;
    ClassSelectionCommonView view;

    private void Start()
    {
        data = GetComponent<ClassSelectionCommonData>();
        view = GetComponent<ClassSelectionCommonView>();
    }

    public void SelectClass() // "Start" Button pressed
    {
        Toggle selectedToggle = view.GetActiveToggle(); // Get the active Toggle

        // ... ?
    }
}
```

So when I call the Method `SelectClass()` I do not know how to move on. How could I say that this selectedToggle is class xy?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If there is only script selection issue(Not charachter mesh selection) Then, you should attache both script on the object and [enable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) [disable](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/enabling-and-disabling-components) them on UItoggle.